# Angular 6 - share an object between unrelated components

Tags: angular, rxjs, communication, phaser-framework, angular-components

**The Task:**

I am integrating an existing HTML5 project (a Phaser-based scientific software) into Angular, for the purposes of better structuring of the ever-expanding UI.

The software lies in its own component and is working. All functionality of the software is exposed from a **controller** class. I have an instance of the controller class inside the state of the Phaser project.

Imagining a new component (say, top-menu) I would like to be able to say:

`<div (click)="this.controller.makeAction()"></div>`

, where "this.controller" is an instance, saved in the top-menu component.

**Related research:**

I have read in many places, that the recommended way to communicate between unrelated components is through a service and using an rxjs BehaviorSubject. Ok... here comes the problem:

**The Problem:**

When I create the service, I have to set the instance of the BehaviorSubject. The problem is that I do not know when the game will be ready, in order to acces the state, and thus provide the controller to the service. So.. the BehaviorSubject stays null and I get an error.

I would really like to avoid placing Angular code inside the Phaser project, as they should be kept  as decoupled as possible (currently there is no coupling what-so-ever).

**Questions:**

Is my approach correct? The controller will be given to any UI element, and thus to any component. How to fix this problem?

**Related Code:**

**1. The service**

```
// Omitting imports and decorators
export class UserActionControllerService {
  private _userActionController = new BehaviorSubject<UserActionController>(null);
  userActionController = this._userActionController.asObservable();
  constructor() {  }
  setUAC(userActionController: UserActionController){
    this._userActionController.next(userActionController);
  }
}
```

**2. Using the service in top-menu**

```
//Omitting imports and decorator
export class TopMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  userActionController: UserActionController;
  constructor(private uac: UserActionControllerService) {  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.uac.userActionController.subscribe((value) => {
      this.userActionController = value;
    });
  }
```

**and the html...**

```
<p>{{this.userActionController | async | json}}</p>
```

**3. Setting the value of the controller in the service**

```
//Ommitting imports and decorator
export class GteCoreComponent implements OnInit {
  game: Phaser.Game;
  constructor(private userActionControllerService: UserActionControllerService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.game = new GTE(width, height);
this.userActionControllerService.setUAC(this.game.state.states.MainScene.userActionController);
  }
}
```

The last line yields an error, because the game has not been created yet. I tried with `setTimeout()`, still to no avail.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**EDIT:**

I managed to get it working with setTimeout, which seems like a hack. Any other suggestions?

**EDIT2:**

As per request, here is the GTE class:

```
export class GTE extends Phaser.Game {
  game: Phaser.Game;    
  constructor(width?: number, height?: number) {    
    super(width, height, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-div', null, false, true);    
    this.game = this;
    this.game.state.add('Boot', Boot, false);
    this.game.state.add('MainScene', MainScene, false);
    this.game.state.start('Boot');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should emit an event from the Game Component that will be listened to in the TopMenuComponent. Something along the lines of `init`. You can then do the needful based on this by calling `next` on the Service's BehaviorSubject with the appropriate data.

Comment: Does Phaser.Game have some sort of an event to indicate when it is ready? Or do you need to explicitly call something to cause it to become ready?

Comment: @MarkHughes Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to substitue the last line with: `this.game.load.onLoadComplete(()=>doSomething())`, but the problem is the same. The game has not been created yet in the line `this.game = new GTE(width, height);`, so I cannot access any of its properties.

Comment: What does `new GTE(...)` do then? Is there some documentation for Phaser.Game to indicate how you should instantiate it?

Comment: @MarkHughes `new GTE(...)` instantiates/creates my game. I have a class GTE which extends Phaser.Game, and it is created with width and height. After a couple of seconds, the game is created, visible on the screen and in theory should be accessible via the `this.game` property.

Comment: Are there any other events available on this.game (instead of this.game.load) to tell you when it is ready?

Comment: ... in fact, can you put the code for the GTE class in the question?

Comment: @MarkHughes Added the class. There are `onBlur`,`onFocus`,`onPause`,`onResume`. But still the game has not been created, so no callbacks would help me I feel...

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted that you have solved the problem using `setTimeout`, this indicates that it is a timing matter which is causing your issue.

`setTimeout` does two things:

Firstly, it delays the processing of the callback for some specified number of milliseconds. This can be problematic as if a user's browser is a bit slower/busier, it might take more than the specified time for the thing you are waiting for to become ready. It is always better to trigger such an activity off an event rather than waiting a time - if you wait long enough to be sure it's ready, you'll be waiting much longer than necessary for the majority of users.

The second thing `setTimeout` does is push the execution of the callback onto the next JS execution frame. This can be required in certain circumstances as it allows other queued work to complete before continuing. This will work even if you set the timeout to 0ms - and if this solves the problem, then `setTimeout` is safe to use in this scenario.

Nevertheless, even if you are in the second of these scenarios, keying off an event would be much cleaner - and less likely for someone, or your future self, to come along and un-do it later!

Looking at the [Phaser.Game documentation](https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Game.html) there is an isBooted flag, so if there is no event exposed, you could create one in your GTE class:

```
export class GTE extends Phaser.Game {
  game: Phaser.Game; 
  private readyCallback: () => null;
  constructor(width?: number, height?: number, ready: () => null) {    
    super(width, height, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-div', null, false, true);    
    this.game = this;
    this.game.state.add('Boot', Boot, false);
    this.game.state.add('MainScene', MainScene, false);
    this.game.state.start('Boot');
    this.readyCallback = ready;
    setTimeout(() => this.checkReady(), 100);
  }

  checkReady() {
    if (this.game.isBooted) this.readyCallback();
    else setTimeout(() => this.checkReady(), 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I do it with a custom event, inside my Phaser Game, this would mean using (a) Angular event system which would mean coupling of the Phaser Game to Angular, or (b) using a pure JS event system, which I do not think will be prettier.

Comment: I would look to creating your own event off the isBooted flag available on Phaser.Game - see my updated answer @MartinAntonov

Comment: @MartinAntonov Did that method for using setTimeout with the isBooted flag help?

Comment: Hey. Unfortunately, it did not help, so I have just left it with the original setTimeout. The problem was, that although the game has booted, the controller has not been created through the state.